# adding a web view in a prototype cell

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiwebview

I am trying to add a web view in my table view cell and it won't let me drag and drop a web view. I did further research on creating it programmatically so i tried to do the UIWebView *webView = [UIWebView alloc]init]..... but that didn't work and I am still having issues. I tried loading the web view with tag but that didn't work either. As you can see im still learning and a new developer and it'd be great if someone has a tutorial on working with tags and importantly where do i start when adding a webview in a custom cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014105/where-is-a-good-tutorial-for-making-a-custom-uitableviewcell

[- customizing uitableview cell](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/)

[- customize table view cells for uitableview](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

There are many good example that gives you idea about custom cell and how to use it.

Hope it will help.